# Flash builder + Zend amf | Insertion function not working when called second time

Tags: apache-flex, insert, zend-amf

I'm using standart createOrders function which is autogenerated by Flash Builder 4.6.
It works brilliantly when used once. Here is code:

```
protected function okButton_clickHandler():void
            {
                var orders2:Orders = new Orders();
                //setting values
                createOrdersResult.token = ordersService.createOrders(orders2);
                ordersService.commit();                 
            }
```

When same button is clicked **second** time and consequently okButton_clickHandler launched, data is not inserted to database. 
I added result handler with *trace("saved");* and what I saw was that "saved" was written on first click, but not second.

Also I used **Charles** to see whether request is being sent second time. And no it is not.

**EDIT**
Just tried to generate auto generate form. Only had to add commit(); because else request is not sent. And here is save problem — request is sent only on first button click.

**EDIT 2**
So all in all problem is in fact that ordersService.createOrders(orders2); works only once.
Because if i try

```
createOrdersResult.token = ordersService.createOrders(orders2);
                ordersService.commit();
                createOrdersResult.token = ordersService.createOrders(orders2);
                ordersService.commit();
OR
            createOrdersResult.token = ordersService.createOrders(orders2);             
            createOrdersResult.token = ordersService.createOrders(orders2);
            ordersService.commit();
```

there is only one row added to database.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show `ordersService` code?

Comment: Here it is:http://paste.php.lv/9458b6943eb10d3ea553139b0a9da57b?lang=php

Comment: +1 for using Charles to help find out if the problem was on client or server.  Did you add a breakpoint in the click handler method to validate that the method is executing each time the button is clicked?

Comment: No, but I just did that. And resultHandler is not called second(!) time. But ordersService.createOrders(orders2) is!

Comment: It is defined like this and seems fine:

Comment: <s:CallResponder id="createOrdersResult" result="createOrdersResult_resultHandler(event)">